# How to logout all devices after admin change role for user Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, logout

I building laravel project. I want to build a feature to log out all devices after the admin changes the role for the user.
I searched for Auth::logoutOtherDevices in the Laravel documentation, but this function requires a password parameter, but the password is already hashed so it can't be used.
Is there any other way to log out a specified account from all devices?

Comment: Yes because it's the user that request that using his password, it's the same logic as the login, but for logout of all other devices

Comment: What sessions driver are you using? If you are using redis i always use a seperate database for sessions. the you easily clear this sessions database using various methods.